# Problem with WebDataRocks Pivot Table captions in rows, columns, measures

Tags: webdatarocks

I have 3 questions about captions (data localizations):

- How to provide **caption** for a field not included in **slice** object
- Why are captions ignored in: **toolbar** -> **fields** -> **all fields** -> any **measure** field
- Why are captions ignored while adding calculated value: **toolbar** -> **fields** -> **add calculated value** -> any **row** or **column** field

[Check out this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2u15ryz/)

```
var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
container: "#wdr-component",
toolbar: true,
height: 395,
report: {
dataSource: {
  filename: "https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/data/data.csv"
},
    "slice": {
    "rows": [{
            "uniqueName": "Category",
            "caption": "Category_Localized"
        }
    ],
    "columns": [{
        "uniqueName": "Color",
        "caption": "Color_Localized"
    }],
    "measures": [{
            "uniqueName": "Price",
            "aggregation": "sum",
            "caption": "Price_Localized"
        }
    ]
}
```

}
});

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all these features are currently not working as expected.

As a workaround to the first question though you can simply change the field names in the CSV file you're feeding to the pivot table.